# Why to use websocket and what is the advantage of using it?

Tags: java, http, websocket, low-latency

I tried reading some articles, but not so clear on this topic.

Would someone like to explain me below points:

- Why use websocket over http
- what is full duplex communication
- what do you mean by lower latency interaction

Comment: the K.O. criteria is that a client using sockets doesn't need to request *anything* to the server to get the information.....

Comment: See also: [Does HTTP/2 make websockets obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28582935/4561887)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> Why use websocket over http?

A webSocket is a continuous connection between client and server.  That continuous connection allows the following:

1. Data can be sent from server to client at any time, without the client even requesting it.  This is often called server-push and is very valuable for applications where the client needs to know fairly quickly when something happens on the server (like a new chat messages has been received or a new price has been udpated).  A client cannot be pushed data over http.  The client would have to regularly poll by making an http request every few seconds in order to get timely new data.  Client polling is not efficient.
2. Data can be sent either way very efficiently.  Because the connection is already established and a webSocket data frame is very efficiently organized (mostly 6 extra bytes, 2 bytes for header and 4 bytes for Mask), one can send data a lot more efficiently than via a HTTP request that necessarily contains headers, cookies etc...

> what is full duplex communication?

Full duplex means that data can be sent either way on the connection at any time.

> what do you mean by lower latency interaction

Low latency means that there is very little delay between the time you request something and the time you get a response.  As it applies to webSockets, it just means that data can be sent quicker (particularly over slow links) because the connection has already been established so no extra packet roundtrips are required to establish the TCP connection.

For a comparison in what's involved to send some data via an http request vs. an already established webSocket connection see the steps listed in this answer: [websocket vs rest API for real time data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613399/websocket-vs-rest-api-for-real-time-data/28618369#28618369)

These other references may also be useful:

[Server-push whenever a function is called: Ajax or WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624279/server-push-whenever-a-function-is-called-ajax-or-websockets/38624972#38624972)

[For a push notification, is a websocket mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035467/push-notification-is-websocket-mandatory/31042439#31042439)

[HTML5 WebSocket: A Quantum Leap in Scalability for the Web](http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html)

Comment: `A client cannot be pushed data over http`. It can via webhooks ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28870041/4561887)), wherein the client gives the server a URL that the server can repeatedly POST to whenever the server wants. In this way, the client registers a callback URL with the server and the server can POST to it at-will. You might want to mention this in your answer too.

Comment: Also, please vote to re-open this question.

Comment: @GabrielStaples - Don't forget about [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) (an http form of push).

Comment: so how come it is different from cloud streams?

Comment: @2437850 - If you have a specific question about how a webSocket compares to some particular cloud technology, then please write your own question and describe the details of what you're asking.